# Reading from a binary problems

Tags: c++, file-io

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    using namespace std;

    int v1 = 0;
    ifstream infile; 
    inputFile.open("pointsdata.dat", ios::binary | ios::in);
    inputFile.read(&v1, 4); 


    ofstream file ("pointsdata.bin", ios::binary);
    file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&v1), sizeof(v1));
    file.close (); 


}
```

When I run it I get the error:

```
In function 'int main()':
9:5: error: 'inputFile' was not declared in this scope
    inputFile.open("pointsdata.dat", ios::binary | ios::in);
    ^
```

I have no idea what I need to add or do, I'm really confused, I've tried searching it up but I couldn't  find anything.

Comment: 1. You didn't actually run it 2. Read

Comment: `infile` and `inputFile` are not the same.

Answer (score 2):

Change `inputFile` in lines 9 & 10 to `infile`.

Comment: Commenting and close voting (flagging) is the correct action for such questions.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ What should we flag it for?

Comment: @flatmouse There's an off-topic reason _"Questions about a problem that can no longer be reproduced or that was caused by a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, these are often resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting."_ It's mentioned in the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and accessible through flagging reasons as well IIRC.

Comment: When I change it, it just causes a whole bunch of errors.

Comment: @Alaanor It might be better to read the SO guidelines before asking questions. Also google is always a great help.

Comment: @AliRezaNameghi Well, I'm guessing stackoverflow doesn't take beginners seriously...

Comment: @Alaanor I am a beginner myself.

Comment: @Alaanor We take beginners seriously, but we also have quality standards that need to be held. I'd recommend you post a [MCVE] that lets us reproduce your _real problems_.

Comment: @Alaanor Just try to relax and don't overreact. Sometimes I also get very mad to see how the experienced users treat beginners like a bunch of pets

Comment: @Alaanor `infile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&v1), sizeof(int));`